# Elastic search query Pagination help on Aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have tried the below query for the Pagination on Aggregations but not working properly.

I Am getting the error **"reason": "[40:7] [terms] unknown field [from], parser not found"**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "answer.keyword": "UNHANDLED"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "source.keyword": "QUAL2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "MyBuckets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "question.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_count": "asc"
        },
        "size": "10"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "MyBuckets": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "order": {
              "_count": "asc"
            },
            "size": "3",
            "from": 8
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should show the query you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

Only `size` is supported, you have to remove the param `from` from the aggregation query.
You can try using [partitions in the aggreagtion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions)

Try out the below query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "answer.keyword": "UNHANDLED"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "source.keyword": "QUAL2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "MyBuckets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "question.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_count": "asc"
        },
        "size": "10"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "MyBuckets": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "order": {
              "_count": "asc"
            },
            "size": "3",
            "include": {
              "partition": 1,
              "num_partitions": 10
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks. Is it possible in Partitions to get the pagination from 1 to 10 , 10 -11 , 11-20 etc.If you dont mind can you modify my query add  the partitions aggregation inside myquery. I am new to elastic search, Please do the needful

Comment: @Prabhudas8703 please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a doubt. (Size:"3" &Partition :1, & num_partitions": 10). If I run with this logic I am getting the 3 output. Just wanted to know whether that 3 is between 1 to 10 range?or 1-3 range?.....Also If I execute the above query I am getting record only for Question keyword and not For timestamp is not getting executed with the above logic.

Comment: @Prabhudas8703 can you please share one sample data that includes both `timestamp` and `question` fields?

Comment: I have shared you the sample data. Please check the above one

Comment: Unhandled questions KPI should display top 10 records in descending order also need to add one field for timestamp. **And for all additional records there should be pagination available.** Members should be able to view additional records by navigating through pagination options. Can you some one see my above query and provide me the corrected query for Pagination

Comment: Dear Team, Could you please help me with the Pagination. I need a pagination range between 1 to 10 and 11 to 20 and 21 to 30. Above query is not working for me